# cant mkdir on new server, unsure why

Tags: php, apache, linode

I have recently switched from a website hosted on a normal webhost to a linode virtual server which I installed all of the appropriate bits and pieces to. I moved my code over and everything in my complex web-application works except my image uploader - it is failing to create new folders.

I have gone ahead and placed this in the code to debug

```
$uid = "Blahblahblah";
$thisdir = getcwd() . "/" . $uid . "/"; 

if(mkdir($thisdir , 0777)) 
{ 
   echo "Directory has been created successfully..."; 
} 
else 
{ 
   echo "Failed to create directory..."; 
   echo " this dir Variable is:'" . $thisdir . "'" ;
}
```

which is outputting

```
Failed to create directory... this dir Variable is:'/home/jhstaffo/public/firstclassresearch.com/public/shopper/Blahblahblah/'
```

Why is this happening - is it a server setting or something wrong with my code? What is going on?

Comment: what is the permission of current working directory ?

Comment: `is_writeable( getcwd() );`

Comment: I tried chmod 0755 -R /home/jhstaffo/public/firstclassresearch.com/public/shopper    no avail   is_writeable is offering false though - any idea

Comment: Did you also try `chown` ?

Comment: What should I chown it to it was with www-data or thats what echo `whoami`; is showing - I am not that familiar with linux - just really getting into it

Comment: What flavor of Linux are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears the accurate way to deal with this in a ubuntu server
assuming apache is running using user www-data  - this now functions appropriately

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/jhstaffo/public/firstclassresearch.com/public
```